# Example with redux-observable and redux-form for react-redux-promise-listener

Tags: redux-form, redux-observable

[React-redux-promise-listener](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-promise-listener) contains only example for usage with React Final Form.

What is the right way to use it with redux-forms and redux-observable?

Answer (score 0):

I had some success with using it with redux-observable. Have you seen the [setup linked](https://github.com/erikras/redux-promise-listener#step-1). Helped me when I was working on doing something similar:

```
// createStore.js

...

import createReduxPromiseListener from 'redux-promise-listener';

const reduxPromiseListener = createReduxPromiseListener();

function createStoreWrapper(history, testMiddleware) {
  const middleware = [
    createRouterMiddleware(history),
    createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic),
    createRavenMiddleware(Raven, {
      // Optionally pass some options here.
    }),
    reduxPromiseListener.middleware,
  ];
  if (testMiddleware) middleware.push(testMiddleware);

  const enhancers = [responsiveStoreEnhancer, applyMiddleware(...middleware)];

  if (typeof window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ !== 'undefined') {
    enhancers.push(window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());
  }

  const initialState = getInitialState();
  const enhancer = compose(...enhancers);

  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, enhancer);

  addHandlers(store);

  return store;
}
```

Also see my somewhat-related question [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57681151/how-to-mock-redux-promise-listener-middleware-and-final-form).