# How To Mock redux-promise-listener Middleware And final-form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, react-final-form

I setup `react-redux-promise-listener` [(repo)](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-promise-listener) for `react-final-form` via [author instructions](https://medium.com/@erikras/getting-a-promise-from-redux-actions-d92787894368). Now, I'm having trouble mocking it for testing.

I'm getting error: `The redux-promise-listener middleware is not installed`

I've tried applying middleware within the test provider:

```
// app/frontend/__mocks__/TestReduxProvider.js
import React from 'react';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux';
import { compose, setDisplayName, defaultProps } from 'recompose';
import createReduxPromiseListener from 'redux-promise-listener';

import rootReducer from '../store/rootReducer';

const displayName = 'TestReduxProvider';

const enhance = compose(
  setDisplayName(displayName),
  defaultProps({ state: {} }),
);

const reduxPromiseListener = createReduxPromiseListener();

function TestReduxProvider(props) {
  const { state, children } = props;
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    state,
    applyMiddleware(reduxPromiseListener.middleware),
  );

  return <ReduxProvider store={store}>{children}</ReduxProvider>;
}

export const promiseListener = reduxPromiseListener;
export default enhance(TestReduxProvider);
```

```
// sample test 

import React from 'react';
import TestReduxProvider from '~/__mocks__/TestReduxProvider';

import { render } from 'enzyme';
import Form from '../Form';

it('should not break if no params', () => {
  const wrapper = render(
    <TestReduxProvider>
      <Form />
    </TestReduxProvider>
  );
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

```
// form component relevant

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Form as FormHandler } from 'react-final-form';

import MakeAsyncFunction from 'react-redux-promise-listener';
import { promiseListener } from '~/store/createStore';
import {
  STATUS_SUCCESS,
  STATUS_FAILURE,
} from '~/store/modules/async/constants';


const Form = props => {
  const targetFormErrors = formErrors[targetAction] || '';

  return (
    <StyledForm >
      <MakeAsyncFunction
        listener={promiseListener}
        start={targetAction}
        resolve={`${targetAction}/${STATUS_SUCCESS}`}
        reject={`${targetAction}/${STATUS_FAILURE}`}
        setPayload={setPayloadHandler}
      >
        {asyncFunc => (
          <FormHandler
            onSubmit={asyncFunc}
            validate={isValid}
            initialValues={formattedInitialValues}
            render={({ handleSubmit, pristine, errors, form }) => {
              if (navigationState !== 'form') {
                form.reset();
              }

              return (
                <form
                  onSubmit={event => {
                    setSubmitAttempted(true);
                    handleSubmit(event)
                      .then(() => submitSuccessHandler(form))
                      .catch(() => {
                      });
                  }}
                >
                  {inputsArray.map(formObject => {
                    return (
                      <div key={formObject.property}>
                        <label>
                          {formObject.label}
                          {formObject.isRequired !== false && !isDisabled && (
                            <span className="required"> *</span>
                          )}
                          <InputContainer>
                            <Input
                              formObject={formObject}
                              isDisabled={isDisabled}
                            />
                          </InputContainer>
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                </form>
              );
            }}
          />
        )}
      </MakeAsyncFunction>
    </StyledForm>
  );
};

export default enhance(Form);
```

I was expecting the snapshot to render. However, I got an error instead:

```
The redux-promise-listener middleware is not installed

      103 |     },
      104 |   ];
    > 105 |   const wrapper = render(
          |                   ^
      106 |     <TestReduxProvider>
      107 |       <Form inputsArray={INPUTS_ARRAY} />
      108 |     </TestReduxProvider>

      at Object.createAsyncFunction (node_modules/redux-promise-listener/dist/redux-promise-listener.cjs.js:60:13)
      at new MakeAsyncFunction (node_modules/react-redux-promise-listener/dist/react-redux-promise-listener.cjs.js:82:31)
      at processChild (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2846:14)
      at resolve (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2812:5)
      at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3202:22)
      at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3161:29)
      at Object.renderToStaticMarkup (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3661:27)
      at Object.renderToStaticMarkup [as render] (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:742:31)
      at render (node_modules/enzyme/src/render.js:21:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/frontend/components/views/dashboard/views/accounts/components/__tests__/Form.test.js:105:19)
```

Comment: All `react-redux-promise-listener` does is provide a function that returns a promise, which is exactly what React Final Form wants to consume.

Are you migrating from Redux Form and this was working before with Redux Form?

Comment: This was working in a live environment. Then I was using a test environment -- and it wasn't working. I figured out the issue was importing the `promiseListener` from live store rather than the mocked test store. Solved this by storing that promiseListener in context so that I can dynamically import it.

Comment: Thanks for responding and creating a fantastic library!

Comment: For some reason, I just don't think you should  test this as a bundle. Either test one `middleware`, or your form logic. But not the form with redux integration. To me, there's just so many things can go wrong, which means not worth to test it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I had with reproducing the live environment in the test environment was the `promiseListener`. I ran into this issue by importing directly from store file in the component:

```
import { promiseListener } from '~/store/createStore';
```

solution:

```
// index.js
import createStore, { promiseListener } from './store/createStore';
import { Main } from './components';
import PromiseListenerContext from '~/store/PromiseListenerContext';

const app = (
  <ReduxProvider store={appStore}>
    <PromiseListenerContext.Provider value={promiseListener}>
      <Main />
    </PromiseListenerContext.Provider>
  </ReduxProvider>
```

```
// createStore.js

import { compose, applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import createReduxPromiseListener from 'redux-promise-listener';

const reduxPromiseListener = createReduxPromiseListener();

function createStoreWrapper(history, testMiddleware) {
  const middleware = [
    reduxPromiseListener.middleware,
  ];
  if (testMiddleware) middleware.push(testMiddleware);

  const enhancers = [responsiveStoreEnhancer, applyMiddleware(...middleware)];

  const initialState = getInitialState();
  const enhancer = compose(...enhancers);

  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, enhancer);

  addHandlers(store);

  return store;
}

export const promiseListener = reduxPromiseListener;

export default createStoreWrapper;
```

```
// test store 
import React from 'react';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux';
import { compose, setDisplayName, defaultProps } from 'recompose';
import createReduxPromiseListener from 'redux-promise-listener';

import rootReducer from '../store/rootReducer';
import PromiseListenerContext from '~/store/PromiseListenerContext';

const displayName = 'TestReduxProvider';

const enhance = compose(
  setDisplayName(displayName),
  defaultProps({ state: {} })
);

function TestReduxProvider(props) {
  const { state, children } = props;

  const reduxPromiseListener = createReduxPromiseListener();

  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    state,
    applyMiddleware(reduxPromiseListener.middleware)
  );

  return (
    <ReduxProvider store={store}>
      <PromiseListenerContext.Provider value={reduxPromiseListener}>
        {children}
      </PromiseListenerContext.Provider>
    </ReduxProvider>
  );
}
```

```
// test file 
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'enzyme';
import Main from '../Main';
import TestReduxProvider from '~/__mocks__/TestReduxProvider';

it('should not break with basic params', () => {
  const wrapper = render(
    <TestReduxProvider>
      <Main pageObject={{}} />
    </TestReduxProvider>
  );
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```